# How to set default text for bash whiptail input boxes?

Tags: bash, whiptail

I am making a simple installer that uses whiptail prompts for user input. I'd like to be able to set the default text. Unfortunately --default-item doesn't work and appears to only be for menu items.

```
MYLARUSER=$(whiptail --inputbox "Enter the user to run Mylar as (usually pi)" 8 78 $MYLARUSER --title "$SECTION" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
exitstatus=$?; if [ $exitstatus = 1 ]; then exit 1; fi
```

I have tried using echo "default" | whiptail... but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my issue was that I am reusing the variable which I am defining. This works thanks to [this reddit user](https://www.reddit.com/r/bash/comments/3xqlco/set_default_text_in_whiptail_prompts/cy6wdsw).

```
MYLARUSER=$(whiptail --inputbox "Enter the user to run Mylar as (usually pi)" 8 78 "defaulttext" --title "$SECTION" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
exitstatus=$?; if [ $exitstatus = 1 ]; then exit 1; fi
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with reusing the variable. You just needed to assign a value to it first (specifically, the default text). If you use the variable as the default text, and it was not defined, then of course there would be no default text shown.

Comment: @rici, it is probably an issue if the first time I am defining it I am using the same variable as the text. Notice I'm using a nested variable (or I forget the right name).

Comment: There is no such thing as a nested variable in bash. Inside the command substitution, you have an environment with a copy of all the variables from the outer shell, modifications won't work but that's irrelevant here. The key is to define the variable first. eg. `V="default text"; V=$(whiptail --input "Question" 8 78 "$V" --title ...)`. In your case, I suppose you would start with `MYLARUSER=pi;` to set the default.

Comment: Exactly @rici that was my point. It makes little sense for me to define the variable the first time and then use it again as the default text. It is good to know that you can reuse the variable though.

Comment: Actually, it is a common idiom. Suppose you have an app where the same question is asked multiple times during a session. It may be logical that the default answer each time is whatever was answered the previous time. Then you would initialize the variable to some default, and each question would have the variable both as the default and to store the result.